# I cannot play my recorded audio file using AVAudioPlayer from documents directory on my iPad device (ios 6.1)

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I cannot play my audio file which I recorded using AVAdioRecorder on my ipad device (ios 6.1). But the file plays on the ipad simulator.

Here is the code I use to record and save my file :

```
NSString *tempPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@.aiff",txtName.text];
filePath = [NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:tempPath];


NSDictionary *recordSettings =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:

 [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],AVSampleRateKey,
 [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM],AVFormatIDKey,
 [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,nil];

soundRecorder =[[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] settings: recordSettings error: nil];
soundRecorder.delegate=self;
[soundRecorder record];
```

And the following code to play the recorded file :

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  

NSString *strPath=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString*strName=[arrayAudio objectAtIndex:clicktag];
strPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",strPath,strName];
NSLog(@"path=%@",strPath);
NSError* err;

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath] error:&err];
player.delegate = self;

  [player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

Can anyone suggest some solution to this typical problem. I have searched a lot on stackoverflow and other sites but none of the solutions could help me with my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is Audio playing in ipad simulator perfectly?

Comment: @Ganapathy : yes my audio is playing perfectly in ipad simulator

Comment: check the presence of the recorded audio files and path before playing the audio file. i have checked ur code in iphone 5 (ios6.1) its working good in playing the audio file.

Comment: if the path was incorrect than it would have thrown exception. but i don't get any exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, try setting the session category to *PlayAndRecord:

```
audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
```

(translating from the RubyMotion code I'm writing, apologies if it needs more work)